# Troubleshooting of JavaScript/JQuery code with .show() and .hide() functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a web-page that has header and footer that stay the same and two alternative groups of elements that will replace each other as a user navigates the site. Web page is being built with `JavaScript`, `JQuery`, `Bootstrap`.

Here are an extremely simplified `index.html` and the exact copy of my `JavaScript`/ `JQuery` functions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>Header</header>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- if I remove the below form and just leave a stand-alone button
             (no longer type="submit") it will work as expected by me -->
            <form role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Main text field" id="main_input">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="main_search" onclick="OpenSearchScreen()">Switch to Search</button>
            </form>
            <div class="row" id="mainDiv">
                <br/>
                <p>We are in Main</p>
             </div>

            <div class="row" id="searchDiv" hidden>
                <br/>
                <p>We are in Search</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <footer>Footer</footer>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="misc.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
// hides parts of Home screen
// shows Search screen
function OpenSearchScreen() {
    // hide Main components
    $("[id^='main']").hide();

    // reveal Search components
    $("[id^='search']").show();
}

// hides Search screen
// shows Home screen
function OpenHomeScreen() {
    // hide Search components
    $("[id^='search']").hide();

    // reveal Main components
    $("[id^='main']").show();
}
```

The above `HTML + JS` combination **does not** work: it briefly shows `Search` and then reverts back to `Main`.

As I indicated in the comments, if I remove the `form` and just put in a *regular* (stand-alone) `button` with the same `onclick` setting, everything works as expected: when I press the button `Main` switches to `Search` and stays as such.

I have the following two questions/requests:

1. If you know why it's happening please enlighten me. If have an idea how it can be fixed / worked around please share it with me as well.
2. If you can suggest how I can further troubleshoot the problem please do. I'm completely at loss how to proceed, since I can seemingly debug (via Chrome Dev Tools) the `JS` part only. As soon as the program gets past `OpenSearchScreen` function and then exits `form` element I can no longer track its progress.

Comment: Why are you using `id^='main'` as the selector instead of just `#mainDiv`? You realize that also matches `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="main_search"`?

Comment: @steveax - Yes, I'm quite aware of this fact. I'm intentionally disabling all `main*` elements and enabling all `search*` ones. I tried to *switch off* the entire form instead of its components, but it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a submit button and not preventing it's default behaviour, hence why it's submitting the form and you're only seeing the change for a split second before the form is submitted.

Instead, you could use something like:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="main_search" onclick="OpenSearchScreen(); return false;">
   Switch to Search   
</button>
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UZQkW/)

Or better yet, remove all the inline JS and handle that externally.

Comment: What do you mean by "externally"? Attach an `event handler` to this button programmatically? If so, why is it better? Also further down the road I will need to send the form data to the web-server. Will this `return false;` fix interfere with this functionality?

Comment: @PM77-1 It's just better to keep JS and HTML separate - and yeah, you could use event.preventDefault(), [like I have done here](http://jsfiddle.net/UZQkW/2/), instead. I can't see it affecting any other functionality you have, obviously if you did it that way you'd have to submit the form from inside your method, as we are removing the form submission part with return false in my answer